# Error Installing SSL via Let's Encrypt in Plesk

Tags: ssl-certificate, plesk, lets-encrypt

I am getting an error in only a few domains on plesk. 90% of the time I can install, but there are 10% of the domain where I cannot install the SSL, and I get this error code:

```
Error: Let's Encrypt SSL certificate installation failed: Failed letsencrypt execution: Saving debug log to /**/***/***/***/**/letsencrypt/logs/letsencrypt.log
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for **********.**
http-01 challenge for www.**********.**
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 127.0.0.1
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. **********.** (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Could not connect to www.**********.**.well-known
IMPORTANT NOTES:
- The following errors were reported by the server:

Domain: infraquinta.pt
Type: connection
Detail: Could not connect to www.***********.**.well-known

To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

I don't understand what to do. The site has a public ip of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hi Ignacio Correia,**

actually, you have an additional redirect from **hXXp://www.YOUR-DOMAIN.COM** to **hXXp://www.YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/pt/**, which leads to current issues, because the Let's Encrypt certbot places it's challenge INSIDE the folder "/var/www/vhosts/YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/**httpdocs/.well-known**" for hXXp://www.YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/.well-known and not inside the folder "/var/www/vhosts/YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/**httpdocs/pt/.well-known**".